# Laravel upload image

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to working with image upload in Laravel 8.

I try this: https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-8-image-upload-tutorial/#comment-1459
but I'm getting Page Expired.

I also try this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQaU8FN3PT8
but in this, I get the message `Call to a member function extension() on null`

Here my form page:

```
 @if (isset($empresa))
       <form name="formEdit" id="formEdit" method="post" action="{{url("produto/$produto->id")}}">
       
  @else
       <form name="formCad" id="formCad" method="post" action="{{url('produtos')}}">
  @endif
   
       <form action="{{url('produtos')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           @csrf
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome do produto:" value="{{$produto->nome ?? ''}}" required><br>
           <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id" id="categoria_id" required>
           <option value="{{$produto->relCategoria->categoria_id ?? ''}}">{{$produto->relCategoria->name ?? 'Categoria'}}</option>
               @foreach($categoria as $categorias)
                    <option value="{{$categorias->id}}">{{$categorias->nome}}</option>
                @endforeach             
           </select><br>
           <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Descrição do produto" name="descricao" id="descricao"></textarea><p></p>
           <label for="file">Escolha uma foto para o produto</label>
           <input id="image" type="file" name="image" class="form-control" accept="image/*"><br>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
       </form>
       <br>
       <br>
  </div>
```

In a few words, I realize that the image file does not reach the store function. :(
Any idea what's happening? Maybe is an environmental problem that I deal with...

My controller was like in tutorial video link:

```
$name = $request->name;
$image = $request->file('image');
$imageName = time().'.'.$image->extension();
$image->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add your controller code

Comment: You should put `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  in every form tag

Comment: Thanks Haron, that was the problem.